# Некорректное поведение TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Есть форма winforms, на ней `TableLayoutPanel` `{.Dock = Fill, .RowCount = 37, .ColumnCount = 4}`. 
[image: скрин формы]
Всё было хорошо, а потом такой глюк -- на скрине видны два `Label`: `label1 {.Column = 0, .Row = 31}` и `label2 {.Column = 1, .Row = 31}`. Как видите label2 находится под label1, а не справа, как должно быть. В Runtime тоже самое. Баг не только неприятен, он не даёт возможности отредактировать форму, как надо. В файле MyForm.designer.cs всё гладко:

```
this.tlpEdit.Controls.Add(this.label1, 0, 31);
this.tlpEdit.Controls.Add(this.label2, 1, 31);
```

, в MyForm.resx вообще нет упоминаний. Кто виноват и что делать?

Comment: уверены что у `Label`-ов правильно прописано свойство `Parent` и они принадлежать гриду?

Comment: Свойство Parent не доступно в дизайнере, но его значение в Runtime `==tlpEdit`

Comment: хм... проверьте еще значение `colSpan`, по затененному фрагменту таблицы видно что некоторые ячейки используют объединение столбцов, может побочный эффект

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На тестовом проекте удалось выяснить, что подобное является побочным эффектом использования свойства `ColumnSpan` > 1. Например есть таблица 2Х2. В ячейках [0,0] и [0,1] размещены два `Label`. `ColumnSpan` обоих `Label` равен 1 - все отлично. Как только мы у первого `Label` в ячейке [0,0] зададим `ColumnSpan = 2`, второй `Label` автоматически съедет в ближайшую доступную ячейку с координатами [1,0], НО при этом в свойствах будут указаны его первоначальные координаты.

Дальше больше. Если последующие ячейки заняты, то все они последовательно будут сдвинуты на одну вправо, и как только место справа закончится - последние ячейки будут вытеснены в начало следующей строки. И так по всем заполненным строкам, если же строк не хватит, недостающие строки будут добавлены в конец таблицы.

Если вы выставите у контрола в последнем столбце свойство `ColumnSpan` > 1, то он автоматически съедет на следующую строку. А если после этого в освободившуюся ячейку разместить новый контрол, то у вас будет 2 контрола с одинаковыми координатами на гриде.

Подобный побочный эффект есть и у `RowSpan`, только он менее болезненный, т.к. столбец просто съезжает вниз добавляя к таблице недостающие строки.

Таким образом получается, что координаты контрола в родительском гриде, весьма слабо связаны с его реальным положением.

Честно говоря я был неприятно удивлен таким не очевидным поведением, но ничего, кроме как принять к сведению и использовать `TableLayoutPanel` с осторожностью, не остается.

Comment: Как оказалось у меня там откуда-то появились невидимые ( с пустым текстом) Label-ы. Ну а дальше всё по вашему описанию. Спасибо.

Comment: @3per и вам спасибо за интересный вопрос, я тоже узнал кое что новое для себя.

Comment: @3per вообще, из личного опыта, конструктором в WinForms лучше пользоваться по минимуму или при первичной разработке интерфейса, когда нужно видеть что и где. В коде оно как-то надежнее и понятнее откуда ноги растут если что.

Comment: А у Вас есть какой-то паттерн для работы с динамически добавляемыми контролами? Дело в том, что пишу сейчас форму, которую нет смысла делать в дизайнере, но если генерировать всё самому, то получается плоский код, в котором сложно ориентироваться в плане структуры. Я конечно, могу завелосепедить свой FormStructureBuilder. но не смог отказать себе в желании поинтересоваться, как это делаете, например, Вы. Если что-то такое есть, то можно переоформить как вопрос.

Comment: @4per ну паттерном я бы это не назвал, просто собираю отдельные группы простейших элементов в UserControl с пробросом необходимых свойств наружу. В дальнейшем оперирую уже этими составными сущностями. Для большинства свойств подходят значения по-умолчанию, если настройка сложная - можно вынести в отдельный метод или локальную функцию. Ну и текущий синтаксис инициализатора помогает структурировать настройку, это который new Class(){<настройка свойств>}. Если настройки всегда одинаковые, можно и наследование задействовать и упаковать все в конструктор наследника.

Comment: @4per в целом, вопрос конечно интересный, но форма SO не подразумевает обсуждений, а я не уверен, что на него возможен однозначный ответ